# Why Service Intent Needs to be Explicit Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

When we start a service like following :

```
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setAction("com.android.myAction");
startService(in);
```

It gives an error : Service Intent must be explicit.

Why is this so. Why android requires service intent to be explicit?

Comment: security ... if there are multiple Activities reacting for the same intent user is asked to chose one ... now, just imagine how it could work for services (I can't) ... thats why you have to point exact component name

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: @selvin it worked for pre v5 (i believe) versions so it could work...

Comment: "it work" ... you mean random or all of services that mach would ran ... bad, bad android  :)

Comment: @Selvin i believe no service started in such case (good good android)

Comment: ah, so "it worked" means "did not throw an exception but did nothing"

Comment: @Selvin startService and bindService are not "void" methods... they return ComponentName and boolean respectively, also how do you know they ddidn't throw some runtime exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a service with implicit intent unlike Activity,  no  user  interface
is involved.  When multiple Services can handle an Intent,
Android selects one at random; the user is not prompted to
select a Service.

In case the malicious Service is bound to the calling application, then the attacker can return arbitrary malicious data
or simply return a successful result without taking the requested action. The
malicious  Service  can  steal  data  and  lie  about  completing
requested actions.

Answer (score 1):

"To ensure your app is secure, always use an explicit intent when starting or binding your Service and do not declare intent filters for the service."([From Android developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html))
It must be because without it other apps will can start your service and etc.

Answer (score 1):

A little more to this :
If we want to use Implicit Intent(With Action Name), we have to use setPackageName like this  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.action.ServicePackageName");
intent.setAction("com.action.ActionNameOfService");
bindService(intent, yourServiceConectionObject, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
//or
//startService(intent);
```

Point to note however is that if Service is local Service; You should use Explicit intent as Service Class is available to you. We can also use in same way as shown above but using Explicit is recommended for same reasons mentioned in some of answers.
For Remote Services(Services in Other apps); Since we can not have Service class available to us; We have to bind to service this way only.